# Redirect Django site request on multiple ports with nginx

Tags: django, nginx-config, django-wsgi

I have a domain say 'mydjango.com' . When its called i want to handle the request on multiple ports on the same IP. 122.34.55.1:8000 ,  122.34.55.1:8001, 122.34.55.1:8002
This is expected for load balancing. I am using wsgi, dgango and ngix.
My nginx config file /etc/nginx/sites-available/djwsgi  is -

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 8001;
        listen 8002;
        listen 8003;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        root /home/raka/djwsgi;
        server_name  mydjango.com;

        location /static/ {
            root /home/raka/djwsgi;
        }

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/djwsgi.sock;
        }
    }
```

But by default mydjango.com is mapped with port 80 only.
Other ports are being called when i am mentioning port number like mydjango.com:8002
What i need is - when i call mydjango.com nginx should call next port every time. 
Like, 80 then 8001 then 8002, 8003, then 80, 8001, .
Please any body suggest any idea !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's what you want. Tell me

```
upstream mydjangoback {
       server 127.0.0.1:8000;
       server 127.0.0.1:8001;
       server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}

server {
        listen 80;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        root /home/raka/djwsgi;
        server_name  mydjango.com;

        location /static/ {
            root /home/raka/djwsgi;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://mydjangoback;
        }
    }
```

Comment: using the configuration suggested by you i moved ahead, it helped. Now i am getting 502 bad gateway error.                                                                                        2020/01/28 11:43:34 [error] 3081#3081: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myvosta.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "myvosta.com"

Comment: Hi ErnestBidouille,  Actually i want to balance the load on django application server. So here my plan is to handle the clients requests on multiple ports. If one port is busy another one will be used by the current request.   So could you share your idea regarding this is feasible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the complete solution. I am posting that here.
This is how nginx and wsgi used to balance the load on our sites and avoid manual running of Django application on server.

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.1.1:8002;
    server 127.0.1.1:8001;
    server 127.0.1.1:8000;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    root /home/raka/djwsgi;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/raka/djwsgi;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/djwsgi.sock;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    listen 8001;
    listen 8002;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    root /home/raka/djwsgi;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/raka/djwsgi;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/djwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

There are many key which could be set in above configuration to achieve extra benefit.
Like in wsgi configuration file we can mention the number of processes.